# unable to parse date with timestamp format in jqgrid

Tags: javascript, date, jqgrid

I am getting date object as JSON string as below.
   `2019-03-12T02:39:38.197+0000` 
As I have tried all the possible format options in Jqgrid nothing gives the exact time. so I have used my own formater.

```
 function dateFormatter (cellvalue, options, rowObject)
  {
    var new_format_value='';
    var date = new Date(cellvalue);
     var hours = date.getHours();
      var minutes = date.getMinutes();
      var ampm = Number(hours) >= 12 ? 'PM' : 'AM';
      hours = Number(hours) % 12;
      hours = hours ? hours : 12; // the hour '0' should be '12'
      minutes = Number(minutes) < 10 ? '0'+ Number(minutes) : Number(minutes);
      var strTime = hours + ':' + minutes + ' ' + ampm;
      new_format_value=Number(date.getMonth())+1 + "/" + date.getDate() + "/" + date.getFullYear() + " " + strTime
      return new_format_value;
   }
```

this way somehow working exactly as expected, but when they access in `IE10, IE11` I am getting `Invalid date` error in console.

Can someone please help me?

Comment: Why you use custom formatter instead of using the predefined `formatter: "date"`? Could you provide **the demo** in jsfiddle, which reproduces the problem? Which line of your code produces the error "Invalid date" message? I suppose it's `var date = new Date(cellvalue);`. I guess that some your input data can't be used as the parameter of `Date` and you have to include some additional tests before. The best choice in my opinion would be to use `formatter: "date"` with the corresponding `srcformat` and `newformat` of `formatoptions`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use momentjs and format date with your custom format

More format at https://devhints.io/datetime

```js
var date = moment('2019-03-12T02:39:38.197+0000');
console.log(date.format('MM-DD-YYYY hh:mm A'))
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.24.0/moment.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: without adding external libraries do we have any other way? `2019-03-12T02:39:38.197+0000` this format is not in javascript ??

Comment: anyway you script resulting wrong date its suposed to be `10:39 AM`

Comment: Date recognizes only specific formats, and you don't have the option of telling it what your input format is, you must parse string for your values. momentjs is very popular library for handling date value

Comment: Which version of jqGrid is used?

Comment: @TonyTomov `4.15.5`  you think jqGrid version issue ?

Comment: @HienNguyen the input date is coming from java as `timestamp` shouldnt have format in javascript ?

Comment: You use free-jqGrid supported from Oleg. We develop and support [Guriddo jqGrid](http://www.guriddo.net). In Guriddo we do not support such input date format. The problem in your script is here: `var date = new Date(cellvalue);` I'm not sure, but the Date can not parse such type of string, which result in error. I think you should parse your date string manually. We will try to support such type of input date in next release getting info for this [format here](http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java-internationalization/simpledateformat.html)

Comment: One more comment. In case you use Java the .197+0000 means 197 milliseconds and + 0 hour and + 0 minutes timezone offset. See the link that I put in my last comment. So the correct time output should be : `02:39 AM`

Comment: @TonyTomov hi thanks for your comments, but I have managed to get it done by `moment.js` which works in all browsers `IE10, IE11`